# Is there a way to build an "or" with has_child using Bodybuilder ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "query":
  {
    "bool":
    {
      "should": [
       {   
          "has_child": {
            "inner_hits":{},
            "type": "emp",
            "query": {
                "match": {
                  "name": "xyz"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "bool":
            {
              "must":
              [
                  {
                    "match" : { "name" : "xyz" }
                  },
                  {
                    "match" : { "_type" : "emps" }
                  }
              ],
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "has_child": {
                    "type": "emp",
                    "query": {
                      "exists":
                            {
                              "field": "name"
                            }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>No, unfortunately.</s>

Actually, yes. I was wrong. OP posted [his question](https://github.com/danpaz/bodybuilder/issues/120) on Bodybuilder's github and received the following answer:

> It's a bit quirky but this is how I'd write it:

```
var inner = bodybuilder()
    .query('match', 'name', 'xyz')  
    .query('match', '_type', 'emps')    
    .notQuery('has_child', {type: 'emp'}, (q) => {
        return q.query('exists', 'field', 'name')
    })
    .build()

bodybuilder()
    .orQuery('bool', inner.query.bool)
        .orQuery('has_child', {inner_hits: {}, type: 'emp'}, (q) => {
        return q.query('match', 'name', 'xyz')  
    })
    .build()
```

> Something to
>   watch out for: the order of the orQuerys matters here, it doesn't work
>   if these are switched, which isn't ideal. I think that's because of
>   how the bool clauses are being merged. Let me know is this isn't
>   working for you.

Comment: Sorry for leading you in the wrong way. I corrected my answer.